# OLS and gradient descent difference?

Tags: gradient-descent

I am doing a course on Udemy on which the instructor applied OLS (Ordinary least square) on a housing dataset. The curve he got was linear,with parameters [10^5,239].
Now When I tried to repeat the same using gradient descent as described by AndrewNg on youtube my algorithm didn't converge.
When I used other data gradient descent was converging,which means my code was correct.
So is it possible that same data do not converge on GD but converge on OLS?

Comment: Andrew NG also explains about Learning rate. Reduce it if Loss is increasing or increase it if Loss is decreasing but very slowly. For the second case, may increase the iteration too.

Comment: Also, though not asked. If GD is one option, the other will not be called OLS. Both the options are OLS. The other option can be called a Closed-Form solution i.e. solving Analytically. GD is the incremental approach

Comment: GD can diverge in some cases, check this link, it may help you:            https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/364108/simple-examples-for-cases-in-which-gradient-descent-diverges/364109#364109.

Comment: For the difference between them:                                                                              
Least squares is a special case of an optimization problem. The objective function is the sum of the squared distances and the solution can be found analytically.
GD is an algorithm to construct the solution of an optimization problem approximately. The benefit is that it can be applied to any objective function, not just squared distances

Comment: @10xAI Thanks man. Costfunction was increasing so i reduced the learning rate. It is 0.000001

Comment: Are the features Standardized/Normalized?

Comment: @10xAI After standardizing alpha is 0.01 !!